# B1/B2 visa holder returning to the US just six months after first visit

Tags: b1-b2-visas, passport-stamps

I have a B1/B2 visa, valid for a 10-year period.

I traveled to the US for the first time in 2016, stayed for four months, and left in August 2016.

I am planning to return in February 2017, just six months after my departure. 
I'm concerned about how that will seem when I arrive at the border, and whether I will be questioned about my reasons for returning so soon.

Am I risking losing my visa since I just spent 4 months in the US and am going back so soon?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying you overstayed? As I read your question, it says you were allowed to stay for 6 months and you actually only stayed for 4. That's not an overstay. Is that right?

Comment: If you come back and let us know what you mean, this question can be reopened.

Comment: Unlike some countries the USA doesn't have hard and fast rules on time in verses time out for visitors but coming back soon after a long visit may lead them to question whether you are a genuine visitor.

Comment: i want to travel in february so i am alitle nervousif it will be a problem

Comment: @britany understood, but your question is still not clear: how many months were you in the USA the first time? Was it 10 months?

Comment: no i was in the usa for 4 months .. i only traveled one time on my ten year visa  . But i want to travel next year february 2017. will that be of any issue going back to the states the second time?

Comment: What is the purpose of your visit? How long will you be staying? Why will you return to your country?

Comment: With your comment, I've taken the liberty of rewording your question to make it clearer and so that you'll get a response. Go to the link provided by @pnuts and you'll see a great answer to what you're asking.

Comment: my purpose is for pleasure and the experience n nyc.. i intend to spend 8-9 days then return to my country

Comment: Getting to point .. all i want to know is what to expect at the POE since it will be my second visit abroad and i havent bend any rules

Comment: @pnuts: Not really -- here there's quite a bit more than a couple of days between the visits.

Comment: @pnuts a couple of days is not six months. If the questions are proposed as duplicates then the other question should be re-written in more general terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect this to be a problem.

B1/B2 visas allow up to six months in the US at a time, so four months, once, is unlikely to be suspicious. Your profile was fully examined when you obtained a B1/B2 visa so you are already in a good position. The fact that your next entry is a whole six months later and only for eight days: you do not sound like a problem case to me.

On entry, you can expect the usual questions about who you are, where you live, what you do for a living, what you intend to do in the United States, where you will be staying, what you were doing on your last visit, and when you intend to leave again. The questions may sound aggressive but they are not usually intended that way; just give short, simple and polite answers to each question.