# B1/B 2 visa cancellation or validity before my next vacation

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am trying to find out how can I check to see if my visa has been cancelled or not before my flight. I've noticed someone's was  visa cancelled the day of their flight at the airport so I am pretty nervous. How can I know if my visa is still safe?

Comment: no i havent been arrested before but because my first trip i spent 4 months out of the 6 months stamped in my passport

Comment: i am just 20 . it will be my second visa on my visa thats why i am nervous

Comment: Because of your [earlier question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80412/b1-b2-visa-holder-returning-to-the-us-just-six-months-after-first-visit) why not just contact the US Embassy or Consulate and ask?

Comment: what can i ask them ?

Comment: wouldnt they contacted me by email if it was cancelled?

Comment: Whether your visa is still valid. No, you would not be sent an email.

Comment: Apparently, you're nervous because on your earlier entry this year, you stayed longer in the US than you said you intended to when you entered. But you didn't overstay, didn't violate the visa, and you exited, showing that visa and everything was fine. The only thing that might happen is that you may be asked why you stayed longer, and whether you will do the same on the next visit.

Comment: https://ceac.state.gov/ceacstattracker/status.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will repeat as an answer: your visa is not cancelled. That almost never happens.

> I've noticed someone's was visa cancelled the day of their flight at the airport

I daresay you are confused about what happened or they had some extraordinary circumstances. Visas do not get just cancelled out of thin air. Your visa might get cancelled / revoked at the border but also only for extraordinary circumstances. You can read the [regulation](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-2006.html) yourself. Serious illnesses, drug trafficking, terrorism and the like are reasons. I *think* you might've noticed if you took part in genocide lately. The least serious but logical thing to happen is people filing for an immigration visa, that can cancel their B1/B2 yes. But that makes sense, doesn't it? By filing for an immigration visa you certainly have stated your intent to stay in the USA so they don't want you to get in as a visitor and disappear.